# How to create Synchronized Data extension in Marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I want to create a Synchronized Data extension of `Lead Object` of SalesForce, basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronized Data extension Automatically creating once you sync the salesforce data in datasource marketing cloud

Comment: This is correct.  Synchronized data extensions are dependent on having Marketing Cloud Connect, which must be set up as an integration.